# Assign data point y value to a different y_discrete axis value (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have a data frame (test) and discrete y scale (ydiscrete):

`test <- data.frame(x=as.factor(c(1,2,3)), y=as.factor(as.character(c("2",">4", "4")))) 
 ydiscrete = c("2","4")`

When I try to plot in ggplot, it doesn't plot the "<4" value since there is no "<4" on the y discrete scale.

`ggplot(data=test4, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_discrete(name="y", limits=ydiscrete4)`

Is there any way to tell ggplot that I want the "<4" value to be plotted as a "2"? The reason I haven't replaced the "<4" with a "2" in the original y is that I want to be able to differentiate between the "<4"s that become a "2" (i.e. with a triangle) and the regular "2" values (i.e. with a circle).

Comment: `aes(x=x, y=factor(y, labels = c(2, 2, 4)))`

Comment: Thank you, @Roland. Is there anyway to do it with an if statement so that I could label the "<4" as a "2" regardless of where it was in the list of y values? perhaps something like: `if (str_detect(test$y, "^<") == TRUE)
  {label = (as.numeric(str_replace(test$y, "<", ""))/2)}`

Comment: The code does not make assumptions about the order of values only about the order of levels. To be save you can specify that explicitly: `factor(y, levels = c("2",">4", "4"), labels = c(2, 2, 4))`

Comment: Thank you, @Roland! That's incredibly helpful. Can I use scale_shape_manual to assign a different shape to each level?

Comment: I think I was able to do it with the following code: `test$y <- factor(test$y, levels=c("2","4",">4"))` & `ggplot(data=test, aes(x=x, y=factor(y, levels = c("2",">4", "4"), labels = c(2, 2, 4)))) + geom_point() + scale_y_discrete(name="y", limits=ydiscrete) + geom_point(aes(shape=y)) + scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,21,24))`